# Can't retrieve posts with auth scaffold

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

Wether I submit the login, register, or forgot password form I can't retrieve the POST data. While this is my form tag:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/login') }}">
```

It doesn't end up in `/login` so I'm guessing it gets redirected back to the current page. How do I retrieve this data anyway?

My goal is to know if a person has used the register/login/or forgot password form wether it failed or was successfull. (They are all on the same page in different modals)

My controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Blog;
use App\Account;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //$this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $blogItems = Blog::all();
        $onlinePlayers = Account::getOnlinePlayers()->count();
        $onlineStaff = Account::getOnlineStaff()->count();
        $input = Request('username');
        return Auth::routes();
    }
}
```

The login form:

```
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/login') }}">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('username') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="username" class="col-md-4 control-label">Username</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('username'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('username') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

                            @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}> Remember Me
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Login
                            </button>

                            <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ url('/password/reset') }}">
                                Forgot Your Password?
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

My Routes:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

//Auth
Auth::routes();

//Homepage
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('/logout', '\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout');
```

LoginController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use \Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Account;

class LoginController extends Controller 
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    /**
    * Override the username method used to validate login
    *
    * @return string
    */
    public function username()
    {
        return 'username';
    }
}
```

Comment: Not very familiar with laravel,shoudnt you have a `Route::post('/login', 'blah@blah');`  route?

Comment: Yes but that happens in `Auth::routes();` but I'm not sure where those files are located.

Comment: Check this link for [Auth::routes();](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/44fe5e08230ed3e36ee0bc31c95f50255e49fd00/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L994) 

And this for the trait [AuthenticateUsers](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7212b1e9620c36bf806e444f6931cf5f379c68ff/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php)

Note on successful logins, you automatically get redirected to `$redirectTo` path

Comment: Auth::routes() is located within laravel/framework/src/illuminate/Routing/Router.php file in the vendor folder and you should not modify these files, instead you could override login method in your LoginController

Comment: You are redirecting to Auth::routes() on Home Controller index method?

Comment: So when you login, where is it taking you that you don't want users to redirect to? And at what point are you wanting access to the POST data? The data is in `$request->input('name_of_field');`

Comment: @SaravananSampathkumar Yes sorry that was for testing purposes to see what it does.

Comment: @DanFletcher I want to access the POST data (prefferably in blade but otherwise I can just pass it on) after submitting the form. Wether it fails or is successfull. The problem is that the POST data is empty.

Comment: @ShadyAtef Thanks that's very clarifying and I'm thinking the problem is ofcourse the redirect in which the POSTs are ofcourse gone.. Stupid mistake

Comment: @SinanSamet you are welcome, and I wonder why you didn't override the `AuthenticateUsers` functions in your model, doing your logic and then calling its functions.

Comment: @ShadyAtef I'm not sure about what you mean. Do you mean the Account model? What should I have overridden? Sorry I'm new to Laravel. I'm curious to your answer.

Comment: In the Login controller, Laravel use trait `AuthenticateUsers`.. you can simply override these functions add your logic and call 'AuthenticateUsers' functions.. In fact this trait is split into many functions, you can only override `sendLoginResponse` and `sendFailedLoginResponse` 
Note : I guess you are using laravel 5.4 from your controllers scaffolding

Comment: Yes I am using 5.4 indeed. And overriding that wouldn't be sufficient I think. I have a couple modals (Register/Login/Reset Pass) and all I need to know is within my view which one was submitted. So I can use jQuery to activate the modal that was submitted so that the validation errors will be visible.

Comment: Removing the redirect didn't solve the problem.. Even if I do `dd()` inside LoginController it doesn't show me anything at all.